# How can I install Mint using Wubi on Windows 8?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I'm trying to install mint 15 on my laptop (with pre-installed windows 8.1) using mint4win. Every time I try to boot up with mint, it ends up on an error screen saying "windows failed to start. a recent hardware or software change might have caused this. The file is missing - file \linuxmint\winboot\wubildr.mbr  - status 0xc000007b". Can anyone tell me how to proceed with mint installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi doesn't work with Windows 8. This is plastered everywhere in the help page and download pages:

> **Wubi does not work on any new PC with the Windows 8 logo or using UEFI firmware.** Please use a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu, installed directly to its own partition instead. For more information see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
>   If you upgraded to Windows 8 and are using BIOS firmware, Wubi does work, but do not enable hybrid-sleep on Windows 8.

source: [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but I just realized that mint4win is wubi based. Can you please suggest an alternative.

Comment: @mindReader no, there's no alternative. The only way, right now, is using wubi. You better install Mint in their own partition instead.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. Can you point me to a guide or something for that? I've new to fiddling with OS.

Comment: @mindReader if I'm not mistaken the installation is pretty straightforward. Just insert the media (USB or CD), configure the BIOS to boot from it, and follow the in-screen instructions.

Comment: I did that & I faced the problem described in my question

Comment: "I'm trying to install mint 15 on my laptop (with pre-installed windows 8.1) **using mint4win**" stop using mint4win. You will be fine. Install the same way as every OS out there, from boot.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that's what you were pointing to. Thanks!